# compute sum of value in an rectangle area of array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a very big array of many value and store it in an `row-major 1d array`.

```
ex:  
   1 2 3  
   4 5 6
```

will be store in `int* array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};`

what I have to do is given the `row1, row2, column1, column2`, then print out the area's sum, and **it will request to caulate different area for many times.**

what I have think about it is first use nested loop to traverse the array and store each row's sum in `sum_row` and store each column's sum in `sum_column` and store the total element's sum im `totalSum`.

Then `totalSum - the row and the columns that surrond it + the elemnts that has been minus twice`.

But it seems fast enough, is there any algorithm that can do faster or some coding style tips that can make the factor little?

Thx in advance.

Comment: just store each column's total and row's in a table then use them

Comment: `int* array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};` is not a "rectangular" / two-dimensional array.

Comment: it ask to print the rectangular area of the rowmajor array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have replaced one double iteration with another. The problem is in subtracting "`the elemnts that has been minus twice`"; unless I'm mistaken, this involves iterating over those elements to sum them.

Instead, just iterate over the rectangular area that you need to sum. I doubt it will be any slower.

A more efficient algorithm can be obtained by generating the matrix of summed upper-left matrices. (See the Wikipedia article on [*summed area table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).) You can then compute any submatrix sum by looking up four area sums.